# Execute command in one terminal and get the output in another terminal it it possible ? how?

Tags: command-line, internet, virtual-terminal, terminal-server

Execute command in one terminal and get the output in another terminal

Comment: Can you be more specific with more information? Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve with what Ubuntu version?...

Comment: What role does *terminal-server* play here?

Answer (score 3):

Possible with something known as `named pipe`.

Here's a basic demo:

1. Open terminal window 1.
2. Type `mkfifo /tmp/myPipe` and hit enter
3. Type `echo "Hello Named Pipe" > /tmp/myPipe &` and hit enter
4. Open terminal 2
5. Run `cat /tmp/myPipe` to see the output

[image]

Another possible solution is to have a `screen` session running, and attach/detach to it.

Comment: Good idea to use screen.

Answer (score 2):

On the receiving terminal, execute the command `w`. This will print a list of currently running sessions, e.g. when I run the command, it prints:

```
 13:39:22 up 11 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.32, 0.50, 0.33
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
sebastia tty8     :0               13:27   11:52  21.10s  0.31s cinnamon-session --session cinnamon
sebastia pts/1    :0               13:36   10.00s 23.90s  0.29s sudo apt-get update
sebastia pts/3    :0               13:37    1.00s  0.11s  0.01s w
```

The one you're in is of course the one with the command `w` (Listed in the column `WHAT`).

In this list, you'll also find a section called `TTY`. There you will see the name of the terminal buffer file, e.g. `pts/3` for the one I executed `w` in.

Now let's assume I want to execute the command running in pts1 to print its output to pts3. This can be done like this (using the command from above):

```
sudo apt-get update > /dev/pts/3
```

This will forward all output to pts3. However, it will not take any **input** from there. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to find a solution for this. (Additions welcome)

---

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, a terminal multiplexer, such as Tmux or GNU Screen may be better suited for this task. e.g. with Tmux, proceed as follows:

Start Tmux with the command `tmux`. You'll be dropped to a new shell. Execute your command there.

In the receiving terminal, run `tmux a` to attach to the existing Tmux session. You can now interact with this terminal.

If you wish to do so, you can detach from Tmux anytime with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, followed by <kbd>D</kbd>. You can reattach from anywhere with `tmux a`.